# How can I solve this error with Immer - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, immer.js

I' like to push the array is from server in empty array in initialState.
As I know to use immer for saving array,

```js
  draft.arr.push({a:1, b:2})
```

But, I don't know why I got the message

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked

I've tried to use `concat` and `push`. But I was not able to get what I want.

```js
const initialState : WorkerState = {
  workersList : []
}

const workers = handleActions<WorkerState, any>(
  {
    [GET_WORKERS_LIST]: (state, action: GetWorkersList) => {
      return produce(state, draft => {
        action.payload.then((res: WorkerInfo[]) => {
           res.map(data => {
            return draft.workerList.push({
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
              email: data.email,
              user_type: data.user_type,
              address: data.address,
              salary: data.salary,
              profile_image: data.profile_image,
              birth: data.birth,
              join_date: data.join_date,
              leave_date: data.leave_date,
              working_year: data.working_year,
              grade: data.grade,
              half_vacation: data.half_vacation,
              total_year_vacation: data.total_year_vacation,
              year_vacation: data.year_vacation,
            });
          });
        });
      });
    },initialState,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you use [handleAction(s)](https://redux-actions.js.org/api/handleaction) function of `redux-actions` package.

It will create multiple redux reducers. Reducers are just **pure functions** that take the previous state and an action, and return the next state.

You shouldn't include side-effect operations in them, like `promise`. You should dispatch an action with the data from the API as its the payload. Then you can mutate the immer draft state directly, just replace the `workersList` directly instead of `map` + `push` the item one by one.

E.g.

```
import produce from 'immer';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createActions, handleActions } from 'redux-actions';

const api = {
  async getWorkersList() {
    return [
      { id: 1, name: 'a' },
      { id: 2, name: 'b' },
    ];
  },
};
const GET_WORKERS_LIST = 'GET_WORKERS_LIST';

interface WorkerState {
  workersList: any[];
}
interface GetWorkersList {
  payload: any[];
}
interface WorkerInfo {}

const initialState: WorkerState = {
  workersList: [],
};

const workers = handleActions<WorkerState, any>(
  {
    [GET_WORKERS_LIST]: (state, action: GetWorkersList) => {
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.workersList = action.payload;
      });
    },
  },
  initialState,
);

const { getWorkersList } = createActions({
  GET_WORKERS_LIST: (payload) => payload,
});

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ workers });
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState().workers);
});

api.getWorkersList().then((res) => {
  store.dispatch(getWorkersList(res));
});
```

Output:

```
{ workersList: [ { id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' } ] }
```